# With Spring Security Core, how to logout the current user without redirecting to another view?

Tags: grails, spring-security

With Spring Security Core, I want to logout before create a new user. So I wrote:

```
def create() {      
    redirect(controller: "logout")
    (...)
```

But LogoutController.groovy redirects to the login page:

```
class LogoutController {
    def index = {       
        redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
    }
```

How could we call LogoutController > index without redirecting to the login page when creating a new user?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788487/grails-redirect-post-logout-using-spring-security-core-3-0-6

Comment: OK. Creating a new logout method could work in this particular case. But in general, is it possible to call a method in background without changing the current view?

Comment: what you mean with 'call a method in background'?

Comment: like in this question @IgorArtamonov, calling to logout without change the current view (create.gsp) to any other.

Comment: but you called 'redirect', it supposed to redirect to another view.

Comment: btw, as you see from the link, you don't need to make redirect to simply logout current user. `SecurityContextHolder.invalidate()` will be enough for your case

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, with `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.invalidate()`, I got the following runtime error: `No signature of method: static org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.invalidate() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`. I also looked for the `invalidate` method in `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils`. I'm using _spring-security-core 1.2.7.3_

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, I know that `redirect` redirects to another view. My question is "what method could we use instead redirect to not change the view"?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's `.clearContext()`, I forgot correct name. Btw, if it's not 'how to call a method' you should fix your question. As about 'what to call' take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727380/how-to-manually-log-out-a-user-with-spring-security for examples (second answer)

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, `org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` works. Thanks! I'm going to change the question.