# How to import Authentication and SecurityContextHolder in grails

Tags: spring-security, grails-2.0

I want to logout manually and I use [Grails Redirect Post-Logout Using spring-security-core-3.0.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788487/grails-redirect-post-logout-using-spring-security-core-3-0-6) to resolve my issues but there is an error of "Unable to resolve Authentication" so can anyone help me how to import Authentication and SecurityContextHolder in grails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you imported:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
```